# Getting current path in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I pretend to auto-include a file for all PHP scripts that are run in the server, so I was trying to use something like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "api/libraries.php"
```

The problem with this is that it will work as long as anyone runs a PHP file located in the root folder. In case someone would wish to run it inside a folder (ex: myfolder/), then the syntax should be:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "../api/libraries.php"
```

I know one solution would be to use the absolute path to the file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/html/api/libraries.php"
```

But, since I'm trying to find a generic solution and I would like this to be able to run fine on any server, no matter what the path is, **I would like to use some kind of "variable" to indicate the current path or generic method**, without the need to modify the absolute path every time I install this anywhere. I don't even know whether this is possible.

Variables like %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} are only available for Rewrite-related functions and it still provides the Root, not the current folder of the htaccess.

I've been searching on internet for a solution, but I was not able to find any workaround to the issue.

Is there any way to retrieve the current folder of the htaccess?
Is it possible to use any kind of variable in "php_value"-related commands?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: No, I don't think you can use any variables in those places. _"would like this to be able to run fine on any server"_ - not all servers will _run_ PHP as an Apache module to begin with; not all servers will _allow_ that kind of configuration to begin with. Maybe dynamically _write_ the .htaccess file from some sort of setup/install script ...?

Comment: Well, sure not all servers will behave the same way, but all servers I usually work with, allow it.